# logstash-output-mongodb plugin v 3.1.7 ArgumentError

Tags: mongodb, logstash

I recently migrated from mongodb 3.0 to mongodb 6.0 and logstash plugin 3.1.5 was no longer working, I upgraded the plugin to 3.1.7 and I keep getting this error in logstash logs:

```
n] MONGODB | Error checking 127.0.0.1:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
n] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 127.0.0.1:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
n] MONGODB | Error checking 127.0.0.1:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
n] MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 127.0.0.1:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
n] MONGODB | Error checking 127.0.0.1:27017: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Here's my logstash configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/shaigaut/logstash.log"
    type => "log"
  }
}


output {
  mongodb {
    collection => "testplugin"
    database => "iris"
    uri => "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
    codec => json { }
  }
}
```

I know this was supposed to be patched with this one: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-mongodb/pull/66

However I still see the issue. Please help.